# Finite order of a distribution

Tags: solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, distribution-theory

[Exercise about distribution theory; definition of a distribution and examples:]

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^{n}$,$f \in L^{1}_{loc}(\Omega)$, $ \beta \in \mathbb{N}^{n}$ multi-index. Consider the linear functional $u$ defined by $u(\varphi)=\int_{\Omega} f(x) \partial^{\beta} \varphi(x) dx$, $\forall \varphi \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega)$.
Prove $u$ is a distribution in $\Omega$, having finite order $\lvert\beta\rvert$.

[My attempt: ]
It is not difficult to prove $u$ is a distribution. Indeed, let $K \subset \Omega$ a compact subset, and $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega)$:
$$ \lvert u(\varphi) \rvert \le \biggl\lvert \int_{K} f(x) \partial^{\beta} \varphi(x) dx \biggr\rvert \le \int_{K} \lvert f(x) \rvert \lvert\partial^{\beta} \varphi(x) \rvert dx \le \sup_{K} \lvert \partial^{\beta} \varphi(x) \rvert \int_{K} \lvert f(x) \rvert dx =$$
$$ = \sup_{K} \lvert \partial^{\beta} \varphi(x) \rvert \lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert_{L^{1}(K)} \le  \lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert_{L^{1}(K)} \sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \le \lvert \beta \rvert} \sup_{K} \lvert \partial^{\alpha} \varphi(x) \rvert  $$
Thus, $u$ is a distribution of finite order. Such order is $\ge \lvert \beta \rvert$: indeed, I have the same case as before for every $K_1 \subset \Omega$ compact, $\lvert u(\varphi) \rvert \le \lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert_{L^{1}(K_1)} \sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \le \lvert \beta \rvert} \sup_{K_1} \lvert \partial^{\alpha} \varphi(x) \rvert$.

However, it is not trivial to me to prove order $\le \lvert \beta \rvert$. Roughly speaking, if order is $< \lvert \beta \rvert$, I don't have information about $\sup_K \lvert \partial ^{\beta} \varphi \rvert$ and the inequality involving $\sum \sup_K \lvert \partial ^{\alpha} \varphi \rvert$ may lead to a contradiction. The problem is I don't know how to exactly prove this.
Is my guess correct? Do you have any suggestions to go further that way? Do you think there is a better strategy?

Comment: Isn't the inequality $$|u(\varphi)| \leq \|f\|_{L^1(K)} \sum_{|\alpha|\leq|\beta|} \sup_{K} |\partial^\alpha\varphi(x)|$$ enough to show that the order of $u$ is not more than $|\beta|$?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The problem is how to show that the order is not strictly less than $\lvert \beta \rvert$.

Comment: I don't think that the order necessarily is $|\beta|,$ only that it is not more than $|\beta|.$ For example, take $f(x)\equiv 1,\ f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}).$ Then $|u(\varphi)|=0$ and one can take $N=0$ in the inequality $$|u(\varphi)| \leq C \sum_{|\alpha|\leq N} | \sup |\partial^\alpha \varphi|.$$

Comment: Do you mean $f$ the zero function?

Comment: No, I mean $f$ being constant non-zero. It should have been $\beta=(1)$ above, i.e. $$u(\varphi)=\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \, \varphi'(x) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi'(x) \, dx = 0.$$